# Remove nil values from array and corresponding entries from reference array

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays generated from :

```
@dividends_values = @dividends.historical.map(&:dividend).reverse.last(50)
@dividends_dates = @dividends.historical.map(&:date).reverse.last(50)
```

The first array is an array of float values and occasional there can be a few nil entries in that. I want to remove those nil entries(which is pretty easy with a compact or something like that), but I also want to move the corresponding entries from the @dividends_dates array.

That is because they the dates array is a 1-1 reference to the values array, so index 0 of array with dates correspondings to index 0 of array with values.

What is a good way to do that?

Comment: If `@dividends_values[3]` is nil then also remove `@dividends_dates[3]`?

Comment: Do you want to wind up with 50 entries in each? Or is it ok there are less than 50?

Comment: yes exactly. if @dividends_values[3] is nil it should also remove @dividends_dates[3], that's right

Comment: Make one array of `[dividend, date]` pairs and remove all entries with a `dividend` (first value) of `nil`. Afterwards separate the pairs.

Comment: the 50 is just the sample i am getting, but is irrelevant to the question really. You can ignore reverse and last(50) there.

Comment: @Stefan I know i can map or pluck to create an array of arrays, but i need to preserve the original arrays.

Comment: You could first create an array holding the  set of _indices_ where `@dividend_values` is nil, and then use this auxiliary array to remove the corresponding entries from `@dividend_dates`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, filter by nil. Then break that up into two arrays.

```
@last_dividends = @dividends.historical.select { |d| d.dividend }
@dividends_values = @last_dividends.map(&:dividend)
@dividends_dates = @last_dividends.map(&:date)
```

Better yet, turn them into a single array of `[[dividend, date], [...]]`

```
@last_dividends = @dividends
  .historical
  .select { |d| d.dividend }
  .map { |d| [d.dividend, d.date] }
```

Comment: Actually i need to preserve the two arrays, although i guess i could transpose. But yeah, i am a moron, i should have removed the whole object yeah :D Thanks for that !

Comment: We can [`filter_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-filter_map) now so the second option can be simplified to `.filter_map {|d| [d.dividend, d.date] if d.dividend }`

Answer (score 1):

First let's create a class-like object for illustration.

```
Dividend = Struct.new(:value, :date)
```

```
historical = [
  Dividend.new(nil, "Jan 1"),
  Dividend.new(10,  "Mar 22"),
  Dividend.new(13,  "Apr 21"),
  Dividend.new(nil, "Aug 7"),
  Dividend.new(8,   "Oct 11")
]
  #=> [#<struct Dividend value=nil, dade="Jan 1">,
  #    #<struct Dividend value=10,  date="Mar 22">,
  #    #<struct Dividend value=13,  date="Apr 21">,
  #    #<struct Dividend value=nil, date="Aug 7">,
  #    #<struct Dividend value=8,   date="Oct 11">]
```

Then, for example,

```
  inst = historical[3]
    #=> #<struct Dividend value=nil, date="Aug 7">
  inst.value
    #=> nil
  inst.date
    #=> "Aug 7"
```

---

We may write

```
historical.filter_map do |inst|
  [inst.value, inst.date] unless inst.value.nil?
end.transpose
  #=> [[10, 13, 8], ["Mar 22", "Apr 21", "Oct 11"]]
```

Note that

```
historical.filter_map do |inst|
  [inst.value, inst.date] unless inst.value.nil?
end
  #=> [[10, "Mar 22"], [13, "Apr 21"], [8, "Oct 11"]]
```

See [Enumerable#filter_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-filter_map).

Answer (score 0):

If you have two arrays with corresponding elements, e.g.:

```
values = [1, nil, 3]
dates = [Date.new(2022, 5, 1), Date.new(2022, 5, 2), Date.new(2022, 5, 3)]
```

You can turn them into one combined array of `[dividend, date]` pairs by using [`transpose`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#transpose-method):

```
values_with_dates = [values, dates].transpose
#=> [[1, #<Date: 2022-05-01>], [nil, #<Date: 2022-05-02>], [3, #<Date: 2022-05-03>]]
```

You can then remove the elements with value of `nil` via [`reject!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#reject-21-method):

```
values_with_dates.reject! { |value, date| value.nil? }
#=> [[1, #<Date: 2022-05-01>], [3, #<Date: 2022-05-03>]]
```

And `transpose` again to separate the pairs:

```
values_with_dates.transpose
#=> [[1, 3], [#<Date: 2022-05-01>, #<Date: 2022-05-03>]]
```

The inner arrays can be assigned back to separate variables using Ruby's [multiple assignment](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Multiple+Assignment).

As a one-liner:

```
values, dates = [values, dates].transpose.reject { |v, _| v.nil? }.transpose
```